# Is it safe to feed mosquito larvae to my fish?

Tags: aquarium, fish, safety, feeding, eating

A long time ago, I had a small fish that would not eat any fish flakes/pellets, So I tried my luck with mosquito larvae from outside. It ate those just fine, and after a while, I was able to transfer it over to eating flakes.

This leads me to wonder; Is it safe to feed wild caught mosquito larvae to my pet fish? Are there potential diseases or parasites that could be transferred to my fish?

Comment: Possible danger if your fish doesn't eat all of them: then you get mosquitos in your flat.

Comment: @ Paulo , I guess you have never added mosquito larva to a tank of several fish; one hundred larva last several seconds at the most.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feed fish mosquito larva whenever I can. I am impressed when a fish that has never seen larva, decides in a couple milliseconds, that it is some thing to eat, and does it. In decades of using larva the only problem I have had is dragon fly larva that apparently came in with mosquito larva. Somehow they avoided fish and ate most baby fish before I realized what was happening.